# How to make bar plot group by month year and plot by only those two?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, geom-bar

so I have this code that takes this `N.Content` column (y-axis) and is mapping it against the  `Collection.date` column (x-axis), and it works, but I am having problems with making it only plot bars per month-year instead of month-day-year. As you can imagine instead of plotting about 19 bars, it gives me about 600 bars. Here is  my code:

```
#Format the Collection Date as a date and not a character format
df_var$Collection.date = as.Date(df_var$Collection.date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
str(df_var)



##====================================================================================================

## Make a plot taking our variant_df with x axis being the Collection,date, and the y axis being the N Content, then fill the color by Clade



variant_plots = ggplot(df_var, aes(x= as.Date(`Collection.date`, format = "%Y-%m"), y= `N.Content`, fill = Clade)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position = "fill") +
 
  
  ##Limit the y axis from 0 to 1
ylim(0.0, 1)+
  
  
 # scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits=c(0,1))
  
  
  #scale_x_date Supposed to limit from Jan 2020 - July 2021

  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m-%Y" , limits = as.Date(c('2020-01-01','2021-07-01'))) 

##Print our plot
variant_plots
```

Here is the result of that code:

[image: My plot]

Here is what I need the axes scaled to:

[image]

As you can see, I have like 100x the amounts of bars, because mine is plotting per day. My question is how can I mutate my code to make it plot to look like that on the x-axis?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Map your date values from year-month-day to year-month and then use that variable on your x-axis.